# ¿Cómo "enlazar" un binario alojado en el directorio /bin de Linux con un proceso de C ? fork()

Tags: c, debian, proceso

¡Hola gente! estoy utilizando el lenguaje C en Debian 10 por motivos académicos, en el tema de procesos.
sinceramente es un tema que me tiene todo confuso, he investigado un poco pero se me hace complejo. debo de hacer un programa en C que cree un proceso que lea por la terminal el nombre de un programa alojado en /bin.

todos los ejemplos y explicaciones que he visto solo hablan de la creación de un proceso con fork() pero hasta donde tengo entendido, solamente el ID que devuelve fork() podría ser "manipulable" por decirlo de alguna forma, o legible.

esperaba que me pudieran ofrecer alguna mejor explicación respecto al uso de procesos para ejecutar programas (en este caso, alojados en /bin) porque realmente no se me ocurre absolutamente nada. o algún pequeño ejemplo que se asemeje, para que no me acaben haciendo la tarea.

en código no tengo mucho, nada mas abro el directorio /bin con opendir() y recorro los archivos alojados dentro con readdir().

Comment: `fork()` duplica (podríamos decir "clona") el proceso que llama a fork. El nuevo proceso es idéntico al original, salvo que `fork()` retorna 0 en el hijo y un ID en el padre. Puedes usar eso para saber si eres el hijo. Entonces, en el hijo, deberás invocar `exec()` o una de sus variantes. Esa llamada sustituye ese proceso (el hijo) por una imagen de un binario ejecutable que lee del disco. Así, en cuanto llamas a exec() el resto del código del hijo ya carece de importancia ya que exec() nunca vuelve. Cuando el proceso cargado por exec termine, terminará el hijo

Comment: me funciono utilizar el **execlp()** gracias por el dato. logré resolver la parte de ejecutar el binario alojado en /bin pero tengo una pequeña duda ajena al tema de procesos. se trata de que debo de ejecutar esos binarios uno tras de otro, uno por uno(cuando termine uno, comienza el otro). de modo que lo hice dentro de un ciclo y funciona! pero cuando no encuentra el argumento pasado por la shell pj. _"pwi"_ (no existe) no sé como hacer para que al igual que el bash, mi programa(ciclo) no termine y espere a otro argumento. alguna llamada al sistema que me ayude ?

Comment: El bucle debería estar en el padre. En cada iteración del bucle el padre debería hacer un fork() y esperar a que el hijo termine (para eso la llamada es join()). El hijo por su parte invocará execlp() para lanzar el programa que toque. Puedes tener la secuencia de comandos en un array, y ya que padre e hijo comparten variables, el padre incrementaría un índice en cada iteración del bucle y el hijo usaría el índice para saber qué comando toca.

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto te resuelva las dudas pero quizás te ayude.

Cuando creas uno o varios procesos hijos con un fork() podes hacer que estos se cominiquen entre ellos mediante pipes, redireccionando por ejemplo la salida de un proceso con la entrada de otro.

Te dejo aca un link que explica un poco sobre como funcionan las pipes, espero que te sirva.
http://www.reloco.com.ar/linux/prog/pipes.html